# Ods-plutra-nailes

Tags: expressions

In Archie Armstrong's Banquet of Jests (1641), there's some doggerel about a Welshman. Besides some fantastic evidence of past rhymes (e.g. steale / gaole), there's an expression I'm not sure of. I've transcribed the relevant part.

[image: On a Welchman Arraigned]

> *On a Welchman Arraigned.*
>
> A Welchman having broke a house to steale
>
> Some Cheese, is caught: his Worship scornes the Gaole.
>
> Ods-plutra-nailes wil you not take her word?
>
> Her great Gran-father was a Prittish lord.

What does "ods-plutra-nailes" mean? Is it perhaps a euphemized "God's nails", with an infixed expletive? Or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: I suspect "plutra" is "cod-Latin" for "plus" + -tra (as in extra or ultra), thus giving ~ many. I also suspect - without much evidence - that this refers to the number of nails used to crucify Christ, perhaps as a reference to triclavianism. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triclavianism) Thus "Christ's many nails!"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems the whole of *ods-plutra-nailes* is an oath. Here’s a breakdown . . .

Starting in the [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required), under **nail**, *n.*, we have:

> **II. 5. a.** A nail used in the crucifixion of Jesus. Frequently as a symbol of the Passion, esp. in devotion or meditation. Frequently in
> *plural*.
>  <sub>This is one of the most common senses of the word in Old English and early Middle English texts.</sub>
> <sub>OE—1990</sub>

But hang on . . . following that we have:

> **II. 5. b.** In oaths, etc.: **(by) (God’s) nails** and variants. Cf. GOD *n.* and *int.* Phrases 3b(a). Now *archaic* and *rare*.
> <sub>In these expressions, *nail* may sometimes have been taken in
> sense 1.</sub>
>  <sub>c1390—1954</sub>
>  <sub>...</sub>
> <sub>[usage example] 1600    T. DEKKER *Shomakers Holiday* sig.
> H2v    Gods nailes doe you thinke I am so base to gull
> you?</sub>
>  <sub>...</sub>

Sense 1 for *nail* is *fingernail*. In [By God’s Nails! Careful How You Curse](https://www.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424127887324030704578426911636037892) we find:

> The real medieval obscenities were religious oaths. A phrase such as
> “by God’s nails” was one of the most shocking and indeed most
> dangerous things a person could say in this era. Oaths by God’s body
> parts, such as “by God’s arms” or “by the blood of Christ,” were
> thought to be able to injure Christ’s physical body as he sat at the
> right hand of God in heaven.

Fingernails or crucifixion nails, let’s next look at **od**, *n.<sup>1</sup>* and *int.*:

> A euphemistic substitute for God in asseverative or exclamatory
> formulae. Now *archaic* and *regional*.

So far we have: *God’s [finger]nails! will you not take her word?*

I encountered nothing but dead ends for *plutra* though. Taking a Latin track, I speculated perhaps *plu<strike>s ul</strike>tra* —> *plutra*. But: *God’s further beyond [finger]nails?* Hm.

Then I stumbled upon [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=QagfpxPOdLYC&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=%22By+Gods+plutra+nayles%22&source=bl&ots=DSyyxcHlH4&sig=ACfU3U1nm19oL57lKlOSTkNuiubZuc9VRg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqotfprqzyAhXTKH0KHWuSD0wQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22By%20Gods%20plutra%20nayles%22&f=false):

> As is characteristic in the written representation of historical
> dialect, what we find in the mock Welsh pamphlets is the foregrounded
> use of certain stereotypical expressions associated with WE. These
> comprise the exclamation “by Cods plutter a Nailes”, or variations of
> this expression, such as, “By Gods plutra nayles”.

Welsh, of course! That led me to [Linguistic and Other Distortions in Ballads on Welsh Themes](http://ebba.english.ucsb.edu/page/22), wherein we find:

> The oath *God’s blood and nails* is rendered as *Cots plutter-a-nails*.

So: *Ods-plutra-nailes wil you not take her word?* —> *God’s blood and [finger]nails! will you not take her word?*

Comment: OED says "*nail* may sometimes have been taken in sense 1 [fingernail]" and I believe it's **far more often** taken as the nails of the Crucifixion — especially when paired with *blood.*

Comment: The blood referring to the spear wound. "One of the soldiers pierced his side with a lance (λόγχη), and immediately there came out blood and water. John 19:34"

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Fair enough. I updated my answer slightly to allow for both possibilities.

Comment: Very nice reference. Question: does it seem clear to you what "plutter a" means? Is it a rendering of "platter of", i.e. something like "load of"?

Comment: *Plutter* means *blood*. See the linked article (Linguistic and Other Distortions...) above. It seems it’s a sort of a Welsh-mocking pronunciation, where *b* sounds like *p* and *d* sounds like *t* — like *plut* instead of *blood*. And *a* means *and*.